# Array is not assigning to the first occurrence but completes task for all other rows. "Exception" error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**I am getting the following error for a specific task I am trying to accomplish:**

> Exception: The parameters (null,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange.
> at printAppleCount(Code:84:19)
> at assignNumbers(Code:24:9)

```
function onInstall(e) {
    onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

    ui.createMenu('Invite Automation')
        .addItem('Assign Numbers to Zeroes (Max. 50)', 'assignNumbers')
        .addToUi();
}

function assignNumbers() {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var colC = sheet.getRange("C:C");
    var colCValues = colC.getValues();

    var appleCount = 0; // to store the apple count
    var appleLineAddress = []; // to store the row-no of Apple 0's

    // get the total count and and its row-no

    for (let i = 0; i < colCValues.length; i++) {
        if (colCValues[i][0] == "") continue;
        if (colCValues[i][0] == 'Apple 0') { // Target only "Apple 0" -- not "Apple 00" or "Apple 01" etc.
            appleCount++; //++
            appleLineAddress.push(i+1);
        }
    }

    // Check apple count and divide 

    if (appleCount < 50) {
        printAppleCount(1, appleCount, appleLineAddress);

    } else if (appleCount > 50 && appleCount <= 100) {
        printAppleCount(2, appleCount, appleLineAddress);

    } else if (appleCount > 100 && appleCount <= 150) {
        printAppleCount(3, appleCount, appleLineAddress);

    } else if (appleCount > 150 && appleCount <= 200) {
        printAppleCount(4, appleCount, appleLineAddress);

    } else if (appleCount > 200 && appleCount <= 250) {
        printAppleCount(5, appleCount, appleLineAddress);

    } else if (appleCount > 250 && appleCount <= 300) {
        printAppleCount(6, appleCount, appleLineAddress);

    } else if (appleCount > 300 && appleCount <= 350) {
        printAppleCount(7, appleCount, appleLineAddress);
    }

}



function printAppleCount(caseNo, appleCount, appleLineAddress) {

    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var splitInteger = function numParts(num, parts) {
    var val;
    var mod = num % parts;
    if (mod == 0) {
        val = num / parts;
        retData = Array(parts).fill(val);
    } else {
        val = (num - mod) / parts;
        retData = Array(parts).fill(val);
        for (i = 0; i < mod; i++) {
            retData[i] = retData[i] + 1;
        }
        retData.reverse()
        //Comment the above line to unreverse the result.
    }
    return retData;
}

    console.log("Case No: " + caseNo);
    console.log("AppleCount : " + appleCount);
    var equalSplits = splitInteger(appleCount, caseNo);

    console.log(equalSplits);

    // for the applecount: 113(suppose), the var equalSplits will log [37,38,38].
    // You can print the data now with the equalSplits and appleLineAddress

    var k = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < equalSplits.length; i++) {

        for (var j = 0; j < equalSplits[i]; j++) {
            console.log('Print Apple ' + (i + 1) + ' at ' + appleLineAddress[k++]);
            sheet.getRange(appleLineAddress[k], 3).setValue('Apple ' + (i + 1));

        }
    }

}
```

What this does is assigns "1" "2" "3" etc. at a maximum of 50 per number when targeting a list and replace only "Apple 0" (replacing the 0 with the respect 1, 2 or 3, etc.)

Even more specifically, if there are more than 50 (so two batches if there are 75 "Apple 0") it splits them equally, assigning 37 "Apple 1" and 38 "Apple 2".

The issue comes when running the script. It does the correct actions but skips the first occurrence of "Apple 0" and does not consider assigning it a value in the loop.

Example table:

| row | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Orange |
| 2 | Orange |
| 3 | Apple 0 |
| 4 | Orange |
| 5 | Apple 0 |
| 6 | Apple 0 |
| 7 | Apple 0 |
| 8 | Apple 0 |
| 9 | Apple 0 |
| 10 | Apple 0 |
| 11 | Apple 0 |
| 12 | Apple 0 |
| 13 | Apple 0 |
| 14 | Apple 0 |
| 15 | Orange |
| 16 | Apple 0 |
| 17 | Apple 0 |
| 18 | Apple 0 |
| 19 | Apple 0 |
| 20 | Apple 0 |

It ends up replacing "Apple 0" for only the 2nd occurrence of "Apple 0" (row 5) and beyond. But the first one (row 3) does not replace and is ignored even in the equal split calculation.

Note also that console log is logging "Print Apple 1 at 3" - so it's considering it. In the assigning/setting value process, it's not doing it.

This specifically started happening when I fixed another error by adding a +1 here:

```
appleLineAddress.push(i+1);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You are using the increment operator `k++` before setting the value, so the first occurrence (`k=0`) is getting skipped, and in the last iteration `appleLineAddress[k]` doesn't exist, the array not being that large.

#### Solution:

Increment `k` after setting the value.

Replace this:

```
console.log('Print Apple ' + (i + 1) + ' at ' + appleLineAddress[k++]);
sheet.getRange(appleLineAddress[k], 3).setValue('Apple ' + (i + 1));
```

With this:

```
sheet.getRange(appleLineAddress[k], 3).setValue('Apple ' + (i + 1));
console.log('Print Apple ' + (i + 1) + ' at ' + appleLineAddress[k++]);
```

Or this (I would not use the increment operator in `console.log`):

```
sheet.getRange(appleLineAddress[k], 3).setValue('Apple ' + (i + 1));
k++;
console.log('Print Apple ' + (i + 1) + ' at ' + appleLineAddress[k]);
```

#### Reference:

- [Increment (++)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment)

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to this and didn't realize the order of console log would have affected it in that way.